# Pytorch batchnorm2d: "RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 1 elements not 64"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch, batch-normalization

*None of the similar questions worked. So please do not flag as dublicate*

Pytorch BatchNorm2d expects an input in the format N C H W
where

```
N = Batchsize
C = Channels
H = Height
W = Width
```

as they indicate in the docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html

If we test this using a random Tensor we get an error:

```
import torch
        
n = 32 # N = Batch size
c = 1 # C = Channels
h = 64 # H = Height
w = 512 # W = Width
        
torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(h)(torch.rand(n,c,h,w))
```

[image]

The following code "works", but has the input format "NHWC"

```
import torch

n = 32 # N = Batch size
c = 1 # C = Channels
h = 64 # H = Height
w = 512 # W = Width

x = torch.rand(n,h,w,c)

x = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(h)(x)
```

Comment: Which PyTorch version you are using? It works well in a nightly release.

Comment: @khushiagrawal Can you try again please, I misspasted the "not working" code, that has the format n c h w. It is torch 2.0.1+cu117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing here is, if you are changing the values of `N`, `C`, `H`, or `W` variables, you are actually not changing the internal memory format the PyTorch developers have set; that's just a variable name, i.e., if you provide input in `(n,h,c,w)` as above, internally, `N->N`, `H->C` (H will be the number of channels, instead heights as you are thinking), `C->H`, and `W->W`.

Returning to the question, the number of channels in your input data should match the number of channels in `nn.BatchNorm2d`.

In your case, number of channels you set is one, but BatchNorm is expecting 64 channels from the user. To fix this, you can follow these examples:

Example:

```py
import torch
n, c, h, w = 32, 64, 64, 512
x = torch.rand(n,c,h,w)
x = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(h)(x)
```

and

```py
import torch
n, c, h, w = 32, 1, 64, 512
x = torch.rand(n,c,h,w)
x = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(c)(x)
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks!